# Vertex slide a specific distance instead of a percentage?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, axis

I have a vertex on a 45 degree edge. I want to slide that vertex exactly $0.1m$ on the $x$-axis, but maintain a $y$ and $z$ position along the edge. I can slide the vertex along the edge using <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> for vertex slide, but I do not know the percentage of the length of the edge that corresponds to  $0.1m$. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set *Transformation Orientation* to *View*. In *Edit Mode*, select your Edge and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad7</kbd> to align to your viewport. Now you can manipulate the vertex location by using the *View*'s Y perspective. Select the vertex and press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>-0.1m</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

You can also use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad3</kbd> to view from the side and use the View's X perspective then press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-0.1m</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> but it's not so visually appealing for this example.

Comment: Beware that contrary to vertex slide, this method stretches the UV's.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing the x axis to slide on that axis, then press 0.1 on your keyboard. Your units I think should also be in the same unit (in this case meters) that you want to vertex slide in. You could also do -0.1 or when you vertex slide, a pop up should appear on your bottom left corner of your screen. You can type 0.1 in the slot to make the vertex the way you want.

Comment: see my answer on how to do it properly :D